# 2 Column CSS Layout for 728px and 300px ad display

Tags: css

I've been searching high and low for a 2 column CSS based layout that has a header, footer and a main area which contains 2 columns.  Ideally the left column will display a 728px ad and never be chopped off and the right column will be 300px (for a 300x300 ad) and should be remain fixed, the rightmost side of the right column could be cut off at low resolutions as needed.

Has anyone dealt with a similar issue before?  Obviously the issue arises at 1024x728 resolutions but I haven't been able to find a good way of handling this situation.  I notice digg will sometimes serve up 300x300 ads in their right hand column and they just let the page horizontally scroll but I haven't been able to find/engineer a layout that's comparable.

Obviously, 728+300=1028 so I'm curious how other people have solved this problem.
Cheers!

Comment: Why doesn't just making two floats with the relevant widths work?

Not sure I see the problem...

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need a basic 2 column layout in a non-traditional size.

How much experience do you have creating CSS based layouts from scratch?

First create a container that's 1028px wide. If you create 2 floating divs, one at 728px wide (float left)and the other at 300px wide (float right) you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one you can adapt to your width.

http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/developing_with_web_standards/csslayout/2-col/